# Run Time Error in insert at beginning (head) function in a Doubly Linked List in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

Please point out the mistake in the logic of my code(if any). It is a function attempting to insert an element at the beginning of a Doubly Linked List in C language.

```
struct DLL *insertAthead(struct DLL *head, int newData)
{
    struct DLL *p = (struct DLL *)malloc(sizeof(struct DLL *));
    p->prev = NULL;
    p->next = head;
    head->prev = p;
    p->data = newData;
    head = p;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct DLL *p = (struct DLL *)malloc(sizeof(struct DLL *));
```

should be:

```
struct DLL *p = malloc(sizeof(struct DLL));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Currently you are only allocating the size of a pointer (`struct DLL *`), rather than whatever size is needed for a `struct DLL`.

Note that some people prefer to write the above like this:

```
struct DLL *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

which is arguably more robust.

Note that I've also removed the redundant cast, which is not a bug as such, but it's just unnecessary clutter [and can in some cases be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/253056).

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why did the pointer memory allocation statement(in my code) did not work. I have been using that statement format for quite a long time and it had never created a problem until this time. And why did removing the star from malloc(struct DLL *)  solve the problem?

Comment: @Ultimate he told you in the answer. You only allocated pace for a pointer, you wanted the space for a struct DLL